# SwiftUI padding distance is not consistent

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am using Xcode 12.4 with Swift 5.4 on macos 11.2.2
I want to control the space between two `Text` views. Naturally, `padding` comes to mind. Here's the code

```swift
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
    Text("Exploring San Francisco")
        .font(.appTitle1)
        .fontWeight(.bold)
        .padding(.bottom, 0)
    Text("May 1, 2021 - May 5, 2021")
        .font(.appSmallBody)
        .fontWeight(.bold)
        .textCase(.uppercase)
        .foregroundColor(.init(hex: "666666"))
}
```

Note that I explicitly write bottom padding is 0px. And here's the result:
[image: bottom padding 0px image]

Now if I want 1px padding between them, the padding would become too large. Here's the result of bottom padding of 1 px:
[image: bottom padding 1px image]

As you could probably tell, the distance between them is definitely not 1px, but more like 10px.

However, if I increase the padding to 2px, you could barely see the difference between 1px and 2px:
[image: bottom padding 2px image]

**Why is the padding distance inconsistent?**

The only workaround I found is removing the `padding` and use the `VStack`'s `spacing` parameter:

```swift
VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 1) {
    Text("Exploring San Francisco")
        .font(.appTitle1)
        .fontWeight(.bold)
    Text("May 1, 2021 - May 5, 2021")
        .font(.appSmallBody)
        .fontWeight(.bold)
        .textCase(.uppercase)
        .foregroundColor(.init(hex: "666666"))
}
```

But this is not ideal when there're multiple views in the stack and I want to customize the distance between each pair of them.

Is this a SwiftUI bug? Is there a more elegant workaround for this issue? Thanks!

Comment: May be you want to use EdgeInsets rather than padding. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/edgeinsets

Comment: @greenhorn I tried it and it has the same effect as directly using padding. The distance is still inconsistent. In fact, I believe [the padding function I use](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/padding(_:_:)) is a wrapper of the [padding function with EdgeInSets](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/padding(_:)-6pgqq)

Comment: You can also nest multiple VStacks with separate spacing for each pair your need to customize.

Comment: @greenhorn yeah that's what I am doing right now and i am dealing with more than 10 nested VStack and it's not easy to maintain.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can try and do the following:
basically declare spacing: 0 on the vstack and then change the padding and it will behave the way you want.

```
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
        Text("Exploring San Francisco")
            .font(.title)
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            .lineLimit(1)

        Text("May 1, 2021 - May 5, 2021")
            .font(.subheadline)
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            .textCase(.uppercase)
            .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
            .padding(.top, 1)
    }
```

changing the last line in the example you can see the difference from

[.padding(.top, 0)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHjCQ.png)

[.padding(.top, 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkAdP.png)

[.padding(.top, 5)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlXrO.png)

Comment: It works! So I guess SwiftUI padding is actually adding a View behind the scene and VStack is treating the extra view as something needs spacing. This is definitely something Apple needs to fix. But hey this saves me a lot of time and a lot of stacks :)